# Do unique GET variables in a URI invalidate the HTTP cache, even if it hasn't expired yet?

Tags: http, cache

Let's say cachedfile.js expires in 1 year from now, according to the HTTP 1.1 `expires` header. Will these URI's both be cached seperately in modern browsers?

Request 1

```
cachedfile.js?var=1
```

Request 2

```
cachedfile.js?var=2
```

Assume `Cache-control: public` and the same `Etag`

Comment: If the resource changes, the ETag is also supposed to change. Not doing so could cause you to be on the [wrong end of a multimillion dollar lawsuit](http://www.extremetech.com/internet/91966-aol-spotify-gigaom-etsy-kissmetrics-sued-over-undeletable-tracking-cookies).

Comment: Does apache2 by default automatically change that?

Comment: [By default, yes.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be cached separately.  In fact, one trick developers use to force browsers to pull a new copy of a CSS file after they update it is to append something like ?v=2 to it (e.g. `href="styles.css?v=2"`).